# Description of Tables in DB2 based on dataype

Tags: sql, db2

How can we see the details of columns based on data type for a table in DB2 . 
Like suppose I have a table with 100 columns but I want to see about the columns of data type timestamp only. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux/Unix/Windows DB2, then you can use the [`SYSCAT.COLUMNS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html) catalog view:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA= 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
  AND TABNAME  = 'YOUR_TABLE'
  AND TYPENAME = 'TIMESTAMP'
```

Replacing `YOUR_SCHEMA` and `YOUR_TABLE`, obviously.  If you're on mainframe DB2, then you will use the similar [`SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsyscolumnstable.htm) catalog view:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE TBCREATOR='YOUR_SCHEMA'
  AND TBNAME   ='YOUR_TABLE'
  AND COLTYPE  ='TIMESTMP'
```